# MS SQL Server sys.indexes vs sys.sysindexes system table difference

Tags: sql-server, index, system-tables

For indexes there are 2 system tables: sys.indexes and sys.sysindexes.
I'd like to know what are their differences. Both contain information about indexes then why they are separate?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sys.sysindexes - is [old and deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysindexes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

> This SQL Server 2000 system table is included as a view for backward compatibility. We recommend that you use the current SQL Server system views instead.

you should use `sys.indexes`.

Comment: `sys.indexes` doesn't contain the same data as `sys.sysindexes` though.